# How to access result set in phpDataMapper?

Tags: php, database, orm

I started learning this very nice PHP ORM api last week: http://phpdatamapper.com/
 and have been trying to get up to speed with it

What I'm not seeing in the site documentation, is how to iterate with "$postMapper->all()"?
http://phpdatamapper.com/documentation/usage/finders/

When I try to iterate through the value returned from ->all(), it seems only to have gotten the last element in the table.

Here's the code I have:

```
// $postMapper uses phpDataMapper framework. It works to create the schema & insert values
$postEntities = $postMapper->all();
$postEntities->execute(); // tried adding this to help things
foreach ( $postEntities as $postEntity);
{
  echo $postEntity->title;
  echo "<br/>";
}
```

I see other folks are forking it from GitHub and using it in their projects, so I believe I'm making some mistake in my call logic.

It would be great if someone could share a small example of how to access the query data correctly when using mapper->all()?  This is an important part of a PHP stack and I would very much like to be able to use this particular solution in my projects going forward.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this turned out to be a "not so smart" mistake on my part.  The font in my IDE was too small I guess, and I didn't see the ';' at the end of the line that declares the for loop.

So the ORM is all good, just my code wasn't.  I'm updating this in case someone else can learn from my mistake - other option is to just delete the post all together  (... not sure which is better)

Comment: mcve: [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)